# Django How to Create the Pip and Piplock file?

Tags: python-3.x, django

I am new to Django. How do Pipefiles and Pipefile.lock files get created?

I created them earlier, but I'm not sure what I did.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, figured it out, I needed to type `python manage.py startapp name_of_app`

App has already been created, how can I create the files mid app development?

Answer (score 1):

When you install Django in a new directory with "pipenv install django" you create two files in your new virtual environment and these files are Pipfile and Pipfile.lock

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You should install `pipenv` python library using below command at first in your local machine

```
pip install pipenv
```

Once you done the above setup then you can move to your project directory and and do the below command to create a virtual environment using pipenv module

```
pipenv shell
```

The above command will create a new virtual environment and pipfile. Now you can install the libraries which you want to use for this project using below command.

```
pipenv install libraryname
```

The above command will create a pipfile.lock and update the library details in both pipfile and pipfile.lock files.